# .NET: How to load an image into an ImageList?

Tags: .net, image, imagelist

i have an image that contains a series of images, e.g.:

> [image]

In the olden days, i would load the image into the [ImageList common control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761389(VS.85).aspx) using such API calls as:

- [ImageList_Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761512(VS.85).aspx)
- [ImageList_LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761557(VS.85).aspx)
- [IImageList::Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761435(VS.85).aspx)

What is the .NET method of achieving the same result with the [.NET ImageList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx)?

---

**Note:** The image is only an example. My actual image is a traditional toolbar image list image, with 179 16x16 button images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to add several images included in a single image object.  In this case you'd want to use

imageList1.Images.[AddStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.addstrip.aspx)(imageSeries)

From the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.addstrip.aspx): "A strip is a single image that is treated as multiple images arranged side-by-side"

Comment: You are absolutely right, sir. In my defense such a concept doesn't exist in the Visual Studio designer (whereas a competing product has supported it for 14 years)

Answer (score 4):

What about using imageList1.Images.Add()?